# C# Raw Print , Compress print document, reducing printing file size , Fast Print to printer

Tags: c#, printing

I try to print some jpeg file to my printer. but it will be very very slow printing.

I need to control print file size.

below is my try and fail

Try 1.

**PrintDocument p = new PrintDocument();
 p.Print();
But why my original file is ~100 KB send print file will be grown to 1.7MB????

I just use paint send to print is only 120K or a little grown that is acceptable.**

[windows paint](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyZar.png)

like this
[print job list sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7cvb.png)

Try 2.

**FlowDocument doc = new FlowDocument(paragraph);**

same to PrintDocument file size will be grown up but that is better than PrintDocument just case the file size.

Try 3 RawPrint

**can be sent a file without growing file size to the printer but the printer does nothing.**

Comment: What’s with all the odd questions on SO today?  Has everyone been given homework?

Comment: You know that the JPEG format includes a compression algorithm. When you want to use that Bitmap, you need to decompress it first.